# ClassNotFoundException when unmarshalling

Tags: android, paypal, classnotfoundexception, unmarshalling

I have problem when integrated my app with paypal.
I have succeed to start paypal service but when I try to send my paypal payment it always throw error as following below :

> Class not found when unmarshalling: com.paypal.android.sdk.payments.PayPalPayment

My code as follow :

```
    package com.example.zukami.apps.blynk;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Map;

import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Parcel;
import android.os.Parcelable;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.example.zukami.apps.blynk.bean.AppConfig;
import com.example.zukami.apps.blynk.bean.Coupon;
import com.example.zukami.apps.blynk.bean.Order;
import com.example.zukami.apps.blynk.bean.Paypal;
import com.example.zukami.apps.blynk.bean.User;
import com.example.zukami.apps.blynk.util.BlynkProgressDialog;
import com.example.zukami.apps.blynk.util.CommandResponse;
import com.example.zukami.apps.blynk.util.Flag.DiscountType;
import com.example.zukami.apps.blynk.util.Flag.OrderStatus;
import com.example.zukami.apps.blynk.util.Flag.PaymentOptions;
import com.example.zukami.apps.blynk.util.ResourceManager;
import com.example.zukami.apps.blynk.util.Util;
import com.example.zukami.apps.blynk.util.WebserviceAssessor;
import com.paypal.android.sdk.payments.PayPalConfiguration;
import com.paypal.android.sdk.payments.PayPalPayment;
import com.paypal.android.sdk.payments.PayPalService;
import com.paypal.android.sdk.payments.PaymentActivity;
import com.paypal.android.sdk.payments.PaymentConfirmation;

public class PaymentOptionFragment extends Fragment {

    private static String TAG = PaymentOptionFragment.class.getCanonicalName();
    private static final String CONFIG_ENVIRONMENT = PayPalConfiguration.ENVIRONMENT_NO_NETWORK;
    private static final int REQUEST_CODE_PAYMENT = 1;
    private static final int REQUEST_CODE_FUTURE_PAYMENT = 2;

    private View mainView;
    private FragmentActivity activity;
    private Button ipayButton;
    private Button transferButton;
    private Button ccPaypalButton;
    private Button cashButton;
    private String compId;
    private String paymentMethod;
    private Order order;
    private User user;
    private OrderStatus statOrder;
    private float totalPurchaseOrder;
    private String bankTransferInstructions;
    private String cashOnPickUpInstructions;
    private Paypal paypal;
    private PayPalConfiguration ppConfig;
    private AppConfig config;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        activity = getActivity();
        config = Util.getConfigFromPreference(activity);
        compId = config.companyId;
        new ShowHidePaymentButton().execute(compId);

    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        mainView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.payment_option_fragment,
                container, false);

        user = Util.getUserFromPreference(activity);
        order = Util.getOrderFromPreference(activity);

        ccPaypalButton = (Button) mainView.findViewById(R.id.cc_button);
        ccPaypalButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Log.e(TAG, "ALOHA PAYPAL");
                order = Util.getOrderFromPreference(activity);
                paymentMethod = PaymentOptions.PAYPAL.getOption();
                order.paymentMethod = paymentMethod;

                statOrder = OrderStatus.getOrderStatus(order.status);
                if (statOrder == OrderStatus.NONE) {
                    order.total = totalPurchaseOrder;
                    new AddingOrderToServer().execute(order);
                } else if (statOrder == OrderStatus.PENDING) {
                    Util.saveOrderToPreference(activity, order);
                    Log.e(TAG, "CONNECT WITH PAYPAL");
                    connectWithPaypal();
                }
            }
        });


        return mainView;
    }


    private void connectWithPaypal() {

        String totalOrder = Float.toString(order.total);
        String currency = activity.getResources().getString(R.string.currency);
        String orderNumber = "Order# " + order.invoiceNo;

        PayPalPayment thingToBuy = new PayPalPayment(
                new BigDecimal(totalOrder), currency, orderNumber,
                PayPalPayment.PAYMENT_INTENT_SALE);

        Intent buyingIntent = new Intent(activity, PaymentActivity.class);
        buyingIntent.putExtra(PaymentActivity.EXTRA_PAYMENT, thingToBuy);
        startActivityForResult(buyingIntent, REQUEST_CODE_PAYMENT);

    }


    private class ShowHidePaymentButton extends
            AsyncTask<String, Void, CommandResponse> {

        private CommandResponse response;
        private BlynkProgressDialog progressDialog;
        private String companyId;

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            progressDialog = BlynkProgressDialog.show(activity, "title",
                    "message");
        }

        @Override
        protected CommandResponse doInBackground(String... params) {
            companyId = params[0];
            try {
                response = WebserviceAssessor.getData(
                        ResourceManager.getPaymentOptions(companyId), null);
            } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage());
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage());
            }
            return response;

        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(CommandResponse response) {
            if (response != null) {
                if (response.success) {
                    String json;
                    try {
                        json = response.message;
                        JSONObject jObject = new JSONObject(json);
                        JSONObject data = jObject.getJSONObject("Data");

                        Iterator iterator = data.keys();
                        while (iterator.hasNext()) {
                            String key = (String) iterator.next();
                            Log.e(TAG, "KEY= " + key);
                            if (!data.isNull(key)) {
                                JSONObject opt = data.getJSONObject(key);
                                Log.e(TAG, "OPT = " + opt.toString());
                                if (opt.toString().length() != 0) {
                                    PaymentOptions option = PaymentOptions
                                            .getPaymentOptions(key);
                                    switch (option) {
                                    case BANK_TRANSFER:
                                        bankTransferInstructions = opt
                                                .getString("Instruction");
                                        transferButton
                                                .setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                        break;
                                    case CASH:
                                        cashOnPickUpInstructions = opt
                                                .getString("Instruction");
                                        cashButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                        break;
                                    case IPAY:
                                        ipayButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                        break;
                                    case PAYPAL:
                                        ccPaypalButton
                                                .setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                        paypal = new Paypal();
                                        paypal.id = opt.getString("Id");
                                        paypal.clientId = opt
                                                .getString("ClientId");
                                        paypal.receiverEmail = opt
                                                .getString("ReceiverEmail");
                                        paypal.createdOn = opt
                                                .getString("CreatedOn");
                                        paypal.updatedOn = opt
                                                .getString("updateddOn");
                                        startPaypalService(paypal);
                                        break;
                                    }
                                } else {
                                    continue;
                                }

                            }
                        }

                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage());
                    }

                }
            }
            progressDialog.dismiss();
        }

    }

    private void startPaypalService(Paypal paypal) {
        if (paypal != null) {
            ppConfig = new PayPalConfiguration()
                    .environment(CONFIG_ENVIRONMENT)
                    .clientId(paypal.clientId)
                    .merchantName(config.companyName)
                    .merchantPrivacyPolicyUri(
                            Uri.parse("https://www.example.com/privacy"))
                    .merchantUserAgreementUri(
                            Uri.parse("https://www.example.com/legal"));

            Intent intent = new Intent(activity, PayPalService.class);
            intent.putExtra(PayPalService.EXTRA_PAYPAL_CONFIGURATION, ppConfig);
            activity.startService(intent);
        }

    }



    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE_PAYMENT) {
            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                PaymentConfirmation confirm = data
                        .getParcelableExtra(PaymentActivity.EXTRA_RESULT_CONFIRMATION);
                if (confirm != null) {
                    try {
                        Log.e(TAG, "ALOHAA pAYPAL == "
                                + confirm.toJSONObject().toString(4));
                        // Log.i("paymentExample",
                        // confirm.toJSONObject().toString(4));
                        Toast.makeText(
                                activity,
                                "PaymentConfirmation info received from PayPal",
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        Log.e("paymentExample",
                                "an extremely unlikely failure occurred: ", e);
                    }
                }
            } else if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_CANCELED) {
                Log.e("paymentExample", "The user canceled.");
            } else if (resultCode == PaymentActivity.RESULT_EXTRAS_INVALID) {
                Log.e("paymentExample",
                        "An invalid Payment was submitted. Please see the docs.");
            }
        }
    }

    private class AddingOrderToServer extends
    AsyncTask<Order, Void, CommandResponse> {

private CommandResponse response;
private BlynkProgressDialog progressDialog;
private Order orderToSend;

@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    progressDialog = BlynkProgressDialog.show(activity, "title",
            "message");
}

@Override
protected CommandResponse doInBackground(Order... params) {
    orderToSend = params[0];
    orderToSend.status = OrderStatus.PENDING.getStatus();
    Map<String, Object> orderData = orderDataToPost(orderToSend);
    try {
        response = WebserviceAssessor.postData(
                ResourceManager.addOrder(), orderData);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage());
    }
    return response;
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(CommandResponse response) {
    if (response != null) {
        if (response.success) {
            Log.e(TAG, response.message);
            try {
                String json = response.message;
                JSONObject jObject = new JSONObject(json);
                JSONObject data = jObject.getJSONObject("Data");
                orderToSend.orderId = data.getString("Id");
                orderToSend.invoiceNo = data.getString("InvoiceNo");
                orderToSend.invoicePrefix = data
                        .getString("InvoicePrefix");
                Util.saveOrderToPreference(activity, orderToSend);

                PaymentOptions payOpt = PaymentOptions
                        .getPaymentOptions(orderToSend.paymentMethod);
                switch (payOpt) {
                case BANK_TRANSFER:
                    goToInstructionPage(bankTransferInstructions);
                    break;
                case CASH:
                    goToInstructionPage(cashOnPickUpInstructions);
                    break;
                case PAYPAL:
                    connectWithPaypal();
                    break;
                case IPAY:
                    break;
                }

            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    }

    progressDialog.dismiss();
}

}


    public void OnDestroy() {
        activity.stopService(new Intent(activity, PayPalService.class));
        super.onDestroy();
    }
}
```

I have tried to wrap with bundle object and put as extra parcelable and set class loader of PaypalPayment but the result still same.
Kindly advise what should I do to fix above code and really appreciate for any kind help.

Comment: I'm with PayPal - I've tried and am not able to reproduce this issue.  How are you initializing `activity`?  Are you able to run the SampleApp that ships with the SDK?

Comment: Hi Matt, Thank you for your response. Yes I'm able to run your SampleApp. I'm using this code inside fragment. I will copy paste my complete code. But fyi, before I can run your SampleApp I have to fix the project properties first.

Comment: I have edited my code, kindly advise what is possible caused that make my code cannot send payment request. Thank yoou.

Comment: Hi Matt, I got solutions from my own problem. There was two issue here first is String currency that I got from String value. I put my String value as "RM" (mean is Malaysian Ringgit). I think it cause the trouble. When I change as MYR, the code is running well. Second, I cannot using this code through fragment, it should be directly under activity. When I'm using activity everything is ok. Thanks for your answer anyway.

Comment: Interesting - I put together a small app using fragments and was able to do the payment with the PayPal SDK integration code in the `Fragment`.  Anyhow, glad you have it working now.